# NuGet (former NuPack) and VCS

Tags: .net, version-control, nuget

I'm testing NuGet for the first time today and I'm a little bit disappointed with the documentation and support material for it. I know that it is CTP and that it should probably get better but I feel like the product is incomplete.

I was able to install packages with almost no problem (it crashed once and its a little bit slow) but what now? Should I add all stuff it downloaded into my VCS? I ask that because I got NUnit and NuGet even downloaded the runners for it which I don't think I'm suppose to add to the VCS (and I won't).

I think it should work more like the GEMFILE in rails where you first run a "bundle install" before running the app.

How are you handling this situation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was thinking the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460838/using-nuget-must-i-still-keep-my-3rd-party-library-binaries-in-source-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so other can benefit from this, it's been a while since they release [Package Restore into Nuget](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) so packages don't need to be committed anymore to the VCS.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that yes, NuGet expects you to check-in the /lib folder (and all of its contents) into your VCS. It is certainly not optimized for doing that today though ([see this issue for one example](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/172)).

As far as NUnit including both the runners and the library - this is determined by the creator of the NUnit package. A suggestion to them might be to publish two packages, one with just the libraries and a second package that includes the runners as well.

Comment: I thought that might be a command like "Install-Missing-Packages" or something so every developer could get their own dependencies just like Rails with Bundle